# Fully Transparent Navigation Bar and Status Bar

Tags: java, android, xml, uinavigationbar, android-statusbar

I want to make a fully transparent status bar and navigation bar like Google Play did. When I use window settings to achieve it, the keyboard covers EditText.

**When this code used EditText covered by Keyboard Input:**

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                      WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

**Also this code doesn't make it fully transparent, it just makes it translucent**

```
getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
```

**or this**

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

### I need a window like this:

[image]

Comment: Why not make the navigationBarColor same as the rest of the layout? For example, ```<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>``` colorPrimary or the color that matches your main layout.

Comment: I have already tried that, it is not enough. For example; when i interact with other UI components like drawer layout, color of navigation bar can not integrate to layout's background. It is useful but need more than it.

Comment: Idk what you mean by integrating to background. When the drawer is open, the nav bar and status bar will be dimmed. I beleive that's meant to be like that.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is something like this:

```java
class Utils {

     static void enableInmersiveMode(Activity act, boolean drawBehindNavBar) {
          View rootView = act.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
          int uiFlags = rootView.getSystemUiVisibility();
          int flags =0;
          if(drawBehindNavBar) { flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION; }
          flags = flags | uiFlags | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEEN;
          rootView.setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
     }
}
```

And in your `onCreate` of your activity:

```java
@Override
void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    Utils.enableInmersiveMode(this, true);
    super.onCreate(b);
    // setContentView and the rest of your code here...
}
```

Take in mind that afterwards views will go behind the system UI and you'll need to dynamically add padding to the first and last `View`s so the user can interact with them.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks same as default window.

Comment: Make sure you're not setting the colors anywhere in the code. And your app theme should have `<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>` and `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>` as well

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, you can try this in `your-main-path/res/values/styles.xml`
This is for transparent **Status Bar** and **Navigation Bar** in any android devices.

```xml
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

One more thing if you want to try transparency and float the to the bar you can use this but the background of *Navigation Bar* will reduce 50% of transparency.

```xml
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

When you want to unset the *TranslucentNavigation* float, this one can fit the screen between **Status Bar** and **Navigation Bar**

```xml
<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
```